# Python PIL: How To Draw Custom Filled Polygons

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm wondering if there is a way in [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) where I can draw custom filled polygons, I know I can draw rectangles and circles, what about custom polygons.

Specifically, I want to draw something like the below image:
[image: example img]

How can I achieve this, any ideas. Thanks

Comment: You mean something like the [`polygon`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html) function? (Which, incidentally, I found by clicking your link.)

Comment: I think you'd have to do it piecemeal as, AFAIK, `ImageDraw.polygon()` only draws straight lines.

Comment: You can use `cairosvg` with PIL/Pillow, so if you are familiar and conmfortable with SVG, that may be an option for you.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, Like you said, polygon does straight lines only... I have actually never heard of this cairosvg package I'll check it out thanks, my first guess was to draw a rectangle and then use a circle/pieslice and mask some regions of the circle but haven't really found a way to actually implement that

Comment: That's what I meant by *"piecemeal"* above... identify the rectangles and circles and build them up one piece at a time.

Comment: oh, well could you show me a quick example or perhaps a reference link?

Comment: I don't have anythng to hand, but this may help... https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-imagedraw/

Comment: I know how to draw shapes already, what I'm conflicted about is masking

Comment: You can make an RGB image first, then create an entirely separate alpha layer in black and white and merge it onto the RGB afterwards... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61938943/2836621

Comment: Depending on your basic math skills, it may be easier to create a single polygon. The curved parts can be approximated by straight lines (which is not unusual), with any accuracy you may care about – rough if this must be done interactively, in realtime, or pixel-accurate if it only needs to be calculated once. (But check first if there are any limits in `polygon`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not known for my graphic design abilities or patience tinkering with aesthetics, but this should give you an idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Form basic purple image without alpha
w, h = 700, 250
im = Image.new('RGB', (w,h), color=(66,0,102))

# Form alpha channel independently
alpha = Image.new('L', (w,h), color=0)

# Get drawing context
draw   = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
radius = 50
hline  = h-radius
OPAQUE, TRANSPARENT = 255, 0
# Draw white where we want opaque
draw.rectangle((0,0,w,hline), fill=OPAQUE)
draw.ellipse((w//2-radius,hline-radius,w//2+radius,h), fill=OPAQUE) 

# Draw black where we want transparent
draw.ellipse(((w//3)-radius,-radius,(w//3)+radius,radius), fill=TRANSPARENT)
draw.ellipse(((2*w//3)-radius,-radius,(2*w//3)+radius,radius), fill=TRANSPARENT)

# DEBUG only - not necessary
alpha.save('alpha.png')

# Put our shiny new alpha channel into our purple background and save
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

The alpha channel looks like this - I artificially added a red border so you can see the extent of it:

[image]

Comment: Glad it works for you. Good luck with your project!